# LINUX How to delete file contains certain name?

Tags: linux, shell, rm

I have a file name like this:

```
filelog20161026
```

I want delete it using command linux, is it possible using `rmdir`?
it's difficult because the name of file, especially in part date is always change based on datetime.
so, i want to delete where a filename contains filelog name.
is it possible? I'll run the command programatically and I don't know how to confirm it with `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a glob expression:

```
$ rm filelog*
```

Comment: is it another way to direct delete? without press Y?
i am using the command combine on web in PHP

Comment: @yosafat you can use the `-f` flag (i.e., `rm -f filelog*`) to make `rm` non-interactive, but you should be **very** careful when using it.

Comment: thanks a lot! yes thats what i need! great, thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, you can use regular expressions to run a program for all found arguments.

```
$ rm filelog*
```

will run `rm` on each found file which starts with `filelog` and then continues with any number of any characters.

This will remove all files in this directory. If you want to run it on the whole disk - **very dangerous** - you can use:

```
$ rm -path "*filelog*"
```

**Edit:**

```
exec("y | rm \"filelog*\"");
```

Comment: is it another way to direct delete? without press Y?
i am using the command combine on web in PHP

Comment: Could you elaborate your problem? What do you mean by press Y?

Comment: my problem is i running the command in php using php exec.

Comment: if i try in cli linux, it's work, but any question yes/no in linux command , if press y its successfully work

Comment: exec("y | rm \"filelog*\"");

Comment: @yosafat did it help?

Answer (score 0):

To delete all files with name format `filelog20161026` use the following approach:

```
ls | grep -P "filelog[0-9]{8}" | xargs -d"\n" rm
```

*grep -P "filelog[0-9]{8}"* - will find all files that match specified pattern
*xargs -d"\n" rm*     - will remove each file from list of files found by previous command